# Display static block text based on a products attribute

Tags: product-attribute, products, custom-attributes

- I just have a small code issue - I use the Ultimo Magento theme which has tabs on the product page. I have set up the tabs and they get their info from custom static blocks. Now one of these I want to display a custom block based on an attribute, for example I have 2 types of shoes, and those shoes have different features. In the custom tab block I added

{{block type="core/template" template="page/productfeatures.phtml"}} which has the following code in it:

```
checkAttributeSet($_product, 'soft_sole_shoe_size')): echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('features_soft')->toHtml();
elseif($this->checkAttributeSet($_product, 'toddler_rubber_sole_shoe_size')): echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('features_toddler')->toHtml();
endif;
?>
```

I found some code online which I added to app/code/local/THEME/Block/Product/view.phtml - displayed at bottom.

If I remove the php tags in top code, the tab writes out that code as is on the page, not the block text. If I leave code as is the text does not display. If I just write "hello world" in the productfeatures.phtml that displays on front.

Hoping for advice?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
public function checkAttributeSet($product = null, $attributeSetName = null) {
 if(is_null($product) || is_null($attributeSetName)) return false;
 $attributeSetModel = Mage::getModel("eav/entity_attribute_set");
 $attributeSetModel->load($product->getAttributeSetId());
 if($attributeSetModel->getAttributeSetName() == $attributeSetName) {
 return true;
 }
 else {
 return false;
 }
 }
```

So the whole page code looks like

```
 */
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Default MAP renderer type
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_mapRenderer = 'msrp_item';

    /**
     * Add meta information from product to head block
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/breadcrumbs');
        $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
        if ($headBlock) {
            $product = $this->getProduct();
            $title = $product->getMetaTitle();
            if ($title) {
                $headBlock->setTitle($title);
            }
            $keyword = $product->getMetaKeyword();
            $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
            if ($keyword) {
                $headBlock->setKeywords($keyword);
            } elseif ($currentCategory) {
                $headBlock->setKeywords($product->getName());
            }
            $description = $product->getMetaDescription();
            if ($description) {
                $headBlock->setDescription( ($description) );
            } else {
                $headBlock->setDescription(Mage::helper('core/string')->substr($product->getDescription(), 0, 255));
            }
            if ($this->helper('catalog/product')->canUseCanonicalTag()) {
                $params = array('_ignore_category' => true);
                $headBlock->addLinkRel('canonical', $product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product, $params));
            }
        }

        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve current product model
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        if (!Mage::registry('product') && $this->getProductId()) {
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProductId());
            Mage::register('product', $product);
        }
        return Mage::registry('product');
    }

    /**
     * Check if product can be emailed to friend
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canEmailToFriend()
    {
        $sendToFriendModel = Mage::registry('send_to_friend_model');
        return $sendToFriendModel && $sendToFriendModel->canEmailToFriend();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve url for direct adding product to cart
     *
     * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
     * @param array $additional
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAddToCartUrl($product, $additional = array())
    {
        if ($this->hasCustomAddToCartUrl()) {
            return $this->getCustomAddToCartUrl();
        }

        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('wishlist_next')) {
            $additional['wishlist_next'] = 1;
        }

        $addUrlKey = Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED;
        $addUrlValue = Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_use_rewrite' => true, '_current' => true));
        $additional[$addUrlKey] = Mage::helper('core')->urlEncode($addUrlValue);

        return $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product, $additional);
    }

    /**
     * Get JSON encoded configuration array which can be used for JS dynamic
     * price calculation depending on product options
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getJsonConfig()
    {
        $config = array();
        if (!$this->hasOptions()) {
            return Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($config);
        }

        $_request = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->getDefaultRateRequest();
        /* @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
        $product = $this->getProduct();
        $_request->setProductClassId($product->getTaxClassId());
        $defaultTax = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->getRate($_request);

        $_request = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->getRateRequest();
        $_request->setProductClassId($product->getTaxClassId());
        $currentTax = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->getRate($_request);

        $_regularPrice = $product->getPrice();
        $_finalPrice = $product->getFinalPrice();
        if ($product->getTypeId() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_BUNDLE) {
            $_priceInclTax = Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($product, $_finalPrice, true,
                null, null, null, null, null, false);
            $_priceExclTax = Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($product, $_finalPrice, false,
                null, null, null, null, null, false);
        } else {
            $_priceInclTax = Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($product, $_finalPrice, true);
            $_priceExclTax = Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($product, $_finalPrice);
        }
        $_tierPrices = array();
        $_tierPricesInclTax = array();
        foreach ($product->getTierPrice() as $tierPrice) {
            $_tierPrices[] = Mage::helper('core')->currency(
                Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($product, (float)$tierPrice['website_price'], false) - $_priceExclTax
                    , false, false);
            $_tierPricesInclTax[] = Mage::helper('core')->currency(
                Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($product, (float)$tierPrice['website_price'], true) - $_priceInclTax
                    , false, false);
        }
        $config = array(
            'productId'           => $product->getId(),
            'priceFormat'         => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getJsPriceFormat(),
            'includeTax'          => Mage::helper('tax')->priceIncludesTax() ? 'true' : 'false',
            'showIncludeTax'      => Mage::helper('tax')->displayPriceIncludingTax(),
            'showBothPrices'      => Mage::helper('tax')->displayBothPrices(),
            'productPrice'        => Mage::helper('core')->currency($_finalPrice, false, false),
            'productOldPrice'     => Mage::helper('core')->currency($_regularPrice, false, false),
            'priceInclTax'        => Mage::helper('core')->currency($_priceInclTax, false, false),
            'priceExclTax'        => Mage::helper('core')->currency($_priceExclTax, false, false),
            /**
             * @var skipCalculate
             * @deprecated after 1.5.1.0
             */
            'skipCalculate'       => ($_priceExclTax != $_priceInclTax ? 0 : 1),
            'defaultTax'          => $defaultTax,
            'currentTax'          => $currentTax,
            'idSuffix'            => '_clone',
            'oldPlusDisposition'  => 0,
            'plusDisposition'     => 0,
            'plusDispositionTax'  => 0,
            'oldMinusDisposition' => 0,
            'minusDisposition'    => 0,
            'tierPrices'          => $_tierPrices,
            'tierPricesInclTax'   => $_tierPricesInclTax,
        );

        $responseObject = new Varien_Object();
        Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_view_config', array('response_object' => $responseObject));
        if (is_array($responseObject->getAdditionalOptions())) {
            foreach ($responseObject->getAdditionalOptions() as $option => $value) {
                $config[$option] = $value;
            }
        }

        return Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($config);
    }

    /**
     * Return true if product has options
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasOptions()
    {
        if ($this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->hasOptions($this->getProduct())) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Check if product has required options
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasRequiredOptions()
    {
        return $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->hasRequiredOptions($this->getProduct());
    }

    /**
     * Define if setting of product options must be shown instantly.
     * Used in case when options are usually hidden and shown only when user
     * presses some button or link. In editing mode we better show these options
     * instantly.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isStartCustomization()
    {
        return $this->getProduct()->getConfigureMode() || Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('startcustomization');
    }

    /**
     * Get default qty - either as preconfigured, or as 1.
     * Also restricts it by minimal qty.
     *
     * @param null|Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
     * @return int|float
     */
    public function getProductDefaultQty($product = null)
    {
        if (!$product) {
            $product = $this->getProduct();
        }

        $qty = $this->getMinimalQty($product);
        $config = $product->getPreconfiguredValues();
        $configQty = $config->getQty();
        if ($configQty > $qty) {
            $qty = $configQty;
        }

        return $qty;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve block cache tags
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCacheTags()
    {
        return array_merge(parent::getCacheTags(), $this->getProduct()->getCacheIdTags());
    }
public function checkAttributeSet($product = null, $attributeSetName = null) {
 if(is_null($product) || is_null($attributeSetName)) return false;
 $attributeSetModel = Mage::getModel("eav/entity_attribute_set");
 $attributeSetModel->load($product->getAttributeSetId());
 if($attributeSetModel->getAttributeSetName() == $attributeSetName) {
 return true;
 }
 else {
 return false;
 }
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

hi you have call `wrong  block` as write code in `Mage_Catalog_Product_View`

You can call block type `core/template` that means you call class `Mage_Core_Block_Template`.
 and this `class` is `not  included` function `checkAttributeSet()`;

You need  block type `catalog/product_view`

and this block type work when you in  Product page

So,Please change:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_view" template="page/productfeatures.phtml"}}
```

Above guess that the above code is not need  because just add below code at view.phtml

```
if($this->checkAttributeSet($this->getProduct(), 'soft_sole_shoe_size')):
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('features_soft')->toHtml();
elseif($this->checkAttributeSet($this->getProduct()$_product, 'toddler_rubber_sole_shoe_size')): 
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('features_toddler')->toHtml();
endif;
```

Comment: Hi - thanks so much for the answer. I changed {{block type="core/template" template="page/productfeatures.phtml"}} to {{block type="catalog/product_view" template="page/productfeatures.phtml"}}  and then replaced the second bit of code in the productfeatures.phtml file, but now the page breaks. Half the items on page are missing?

Comment: Hi - my log file shows this error - any ideas? My Attribute Set name in admin is Shoes - Soft Sole so changed from soft_sole_shoe_size which is the attribute name. Was not sure which to use.

exception 'Varien_Exception' with message 'Invalid method Mage_Core_Block_Template::checkAttributeSet(Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => Shoes - Soft Sole
)
)' in /usr/www/users/shooszxjje/shoodev/lib/Varien/Object.php:653
Stack trace: